# PyQt: QTemporaryFile - unable to read from file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, temporary, temporary-files

I'm unable to read from temporary file created by QTemporaryFile, maybe you can check the code below...

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> fileTemp = QtCore.QTemporaryFile()
>>> fileTemp.open()
True   #file is created
>>> fileTemp.fileName()
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'/tmp/qt_temp.TJ2302')
>>> fileTemp.writeData('foobar')
6L     #six bytes are written, great
>>> open(fileTemp.fileName(), 'r').read()
''     #but there is still nothing inside!
>>> fileTemp.size()
6L     #magically, by doing this 'foobar' appears in this tempFile...
       #the same effect gives e.g. fileTemp.readData(1000), but nothing is read
>>> open(fileTemp.fileName(), 'r').read()
'foobar'
>>> fileTemp.readData(1000)
''     #why...
>>> fileTemp.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('')
>>> fileTemp.readAll().size()
0      #why...
```

will be grateful for any help!

**EDIT**

I've extended QTemporaryFile to behave as expected, but still looking for a more clean solution...

```
class MyTemporaryFile(QtCore.QTemporaryFile):
    def __init__(self, *argc, **argv):
        QtCore.QTemporaryFile.__init__(self, *argc, **argv)

    def write(self, data):
        f = open(self.fileName(), 'w')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()

    def read(self):
        f = open(self.fileName(), 'r')
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to force the OS to write the data to a file you should always `flush()`:

```
In [10]: from PyQt4 import QtCore

In [11]: fileTemp = QtCore.QTemporaryFile()

In [12]: fileTemp.open()
Out[12]: True

In [13]: fileTemp.fileName()
Out[13]: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'/tmp/qt_temp.XM5599')

In [14]: fileTemp.writeData('foobar')
Out[14]: 6L

In [15]: with open(fileTemp.fileName(), 'r') as f:
   ....:     print(f.read())
   ....:     


In [16]: fileTemp.flush()
Out[16]: True

In [17]: with open(fileTemp.fileName(), 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
   ....:     
foobar
```

Probably the call to `size()` implicitly forces the OS to flush, hence the behaviour you have observed.

Comment: Thanks, so I know now how to properly write to temp file... but how do I read from it? tempFile.read(1000) returns empty string, tempFile.readAll() returns empty QByteArray. Of course I can always do open(fileTemp.fileName(), 'r'), but why these two mentioned do not work?

Comment: @user2220568 You have to think that each file has a pointer to the current file position. When you create a new temporary file and write `'foobar'`, the pointer will be moved at the end of the data written to the file. `read()` reads the data from the current position onwards, hence the empty string(because after `'foobar'` your file is empty). IF you want to set the current position you can use the `seek` method.  In particular `tempFile.seek(0)` will set the current position at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks! but there is still something missing. after f.flush() and f.seek(0), f.readAll() returned empty QByteArray. But f.flush() f.seek(1) f.seek(0) did the job...

Comment: I just checked that this behavior mentioned above appears only on windows, on linux calling seek once is sufficient. strange. I will append windows code in the answer...

Comment: @user2220568 No idea why that should happen.

Answer (score 0):

so the proper way to do this is finally:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> f = QtCore.QTemporaryFile()
>>> f.open()
True
>>> f.writeData('foobar')
6L
>>> f.flush()
True
>>> f.seek(0)
True
>>> f.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('foobar')
```

but it works only on linux... on windows I had to do something like this:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> f = QtCore.QTemporaryFile()
>>> f.open()
True
>>> f.writeData('foobar')
6L
>>> f.flush()
True
>>> f.seek(0)
True
>>> f.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray()
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> f = QtCore.QTemporaryFile()
>>> f.open()
True
>>> f.writeData('foobar')
6L
>>> f.flush()
True
>>> f.seek(1)
True
>>> f.seek(0)
True
>>> f.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('foobar')
```

maybe to make this more clear:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MyTemporaryFile(QtCore.QTemporaryFile):
    def __init__(self, *argc, **argv):
        QtCore.QTemporaryFile.__init__(self, *argc, **argv)
        self.open()

    def write(self, data):
        self.writeData(data)
        self.flush()

    def read(self):
        #self.seek(1)   #on windows it works only with this line uncommented
        self.seek(0)
        return self.readAll()
```